# Why is no empty argument list required inside this class definition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, templates, c++11

When instantiating a variable that has the type of a templated class using only the standard type arguments, the syntax looks like this:

```
template<typename Arg = int>
class Templ;

Templ<>& myTempl;
```

Leaving out the empty argument list `<>` should give a compile error because a template argument list is needed.

But apparently (at least under VS2013), the following declaration does *not* need a template argument list:

```
template<typename Arg> //" = int" left out
class Templ{
    Templ& myTempl; //no <> here
};
```

But why does this work? According to IntelliSense, the correct type (`Templ<int>`) is selected by the compiler, so it works as intended, but shouldn't the member declaration still require an empty argument list?

*EDIT:* No, it doesn't work as intended. I didn't check it thoroughly enough. When hovering over the line `Templ<short>::myTempl`, IntelliSense reveals its type to be `short`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class name is injected into the class scope

**9 Classes [class]**

> 2 A class-name is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
>   immediately after the class-name is seen. **The class-name is also
>   inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the
>   injected-class-name**. For purposes of access checking, the
>   injected-class-name is treated as if it were a public member name. A
>   class-specifier is commonly referred to as a class definition. A class
>   is considered defined after the closing brace of its class-specifier
>   has been seen even though its member functions are in general not yet
>   defined. The optional attribute-specifier-seq appertains to the class;
>   the attributes in the attribute-specifier-seq are thereafter
>   considered attributes of the class whenever it is named.

and similarly for class templates

**14.6.1 Locally declared names [temp.local]**

> 1 Like normal (non-template) classes, **class templates have an
>   injected-class-name** (Clause 9). The injectedclass- name can be used as
>   a template-name or a type-name. When it is used with a
>   template-argument-list, as a template-argument for a template
>   template-parameter, or as the final identifier in the
>   elaborated-typespecifier of a friend class template declaration, it
>   refers to the class template itself. **Otherwise, it is equivalent to
>   the template-name followed by the template-parameters of the class
>   template enclosed in `<>`.**

so that you can use `Templ` where you mean `Templ<Arg>`.

Comment: And so the OP's claim that it selects `Templ<int>` can only be right if testing with `Arg = int`.

Comment: @hvd my claim is based on IntelliSense's claim that `Templ<int>` was in fact selected, but I should have learned by now not to trust it in template related problems.

Comment: @iFreilicht the actual argument for `Arg` can of course only be known in calling code, and if it wasn't specified it will be `int`, but Intellisense probably messed this up.

Comment: @iFreilicht I figured you were just looking at `Templ<int>::myTempl`, in which case `Templ<int>` and `Templ<Arg>` are the same type. Did IntelliSense really say that (e.g.) `Templ<short>::myTempl` has type `Templ<int>`?

Comment: @hvd Nope, it did that correctly. I should've checked that.

Answer (score 8):

This is called the *injected class name*.

Inside a class template, the name of the template without any template argument list refers to the current instantiation, so `Templ` means `Templ<Arg>` (and *not* `Templ<>` which is `Templ<int>` and so not necessarily the same).